# Weak form of CH in $L(\mathbb{R})$, reference

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, continuum-hypothesis

I've heard someone saying that in $L(\mathbb{R})$ the following form of $\text{CH}$ holds:

> $L(\mathbb{R})\vDash \forall X\subseteq \mathbb{R}(X \text{ countable or } \mathbb{R}\le^* X)$, i.e. every uncountable subset of the reals surjects onto $\mathbb{R}$

Now I'm wondering whether this is a theorem of $\text{ZF(C)}$ or we need to assume some large cardinal to prove it (e.g. so to have $\text{AD}$).
I'm struggling to find some reference.
Any help?
Thanks!

Edit: It cannot be a theorem of $\text{ZF}$ as otherwise we could prove that $\text{ZF}+\text{DC}+\text{PSP}$ is equiconsistent with $\text{ZF}$, which is not. But I'm still not finding a reference for the result under $\text{AD}$ for example..

Comment: For the question in the edit: AD implies perfect set property, which means every subset of $\mathbb R$ is countable or has size continuum.

Comment: @Wojowu Right, right. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about the edit. Why would that shot that ZF+DC+PSP is equiconsistent with ZF? PSP implies a stronger result than just $X$ can be mapped onto $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I should have elaborated a bit more. It is because Truss constructed a model of $\mathtt{ZF}+\mathtt{DC}+ V=L(\mathbb{R})+$ "Every subset of reals of size continuum contains a perfect set", if the statement I wrote was a theorem of $\mathtt{ZF}$ then  Truss' model would satisfy $\mathtt{PSP}$.

Comment: Also if we add $\omega_2$ Cohen reals to $L$, we get a model of $V=L(\mathbb{R})$ in which $L\cap \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and does not surject onto $\mathbb{R}$..

Comment: I still don't understand why that would imply the equiconsistency result. But yes, you are right. One can also use all sort of coding to create more intermediate cardinals that do not map onto the reals.

Comment: Okay, I misread your reply. Truss' model you refer to is not of the form $L(\Bbb R)$, though.